# React router cannot route url with search string

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to click a link with a search string. But the react router does not direct to that page. After refresh the page gets loaded. Is something wrong?

URL

```
 http://localhost:3000/landing?cars
```

Link button

```
                <Button
                 component={Link}
                 to={{pathname: "/landing?cars"}}
                 >
                 Cars
                </Button>
```

router

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/landing" component={Landing} />
    ...
</Switch>
```

Comment: why not just `to="/landing?search=cars"`

Comment: @lala it also doesn't work

Comment: Oh my bad. In `<Route path="/landing/:search" component={Landing} />` and `to="/landing/cars"`. Then in landing page you can use `const {search} = useParams()`. But first make sure to import it from `const { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: or you can refer [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-url-parameters-and-query-strings-with-react-router-fffdcea7a8e9) for both, using `query` or `param`

Comment: @lala Then the routing works, but a hard refresh does not work, the the router doen't know the param I think

Comment: the `param` should persist even if you refresh the page

Comment: a hard reset doesnt remove ur url params. Probably you are using a store to hold the query and it is getting reset on a hard reset

Comment: you can refer to this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aw9pt1?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need an optional parameter:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/landing/:search" component={Landing} />
    ...
</Switch>

<Button
    component={Link}
    to="/landing/cars"
    />
    Cars
    </Button>
```

Then in the Landing page you can access the parameter using the match object. For example:

```
const { searchValue } = this.props.match.params.id;
```

Comment: With your suggestion the routing works, but a hard refresh will  reult in a blanc page, because then I think :search is undefined. With your solution you cannot share the link. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @vuvu What do you mean by share the link, can you create a code sandbox of your issue/ problem?